# Perl: suppress output of backtick when file not found

Tags: regex, perl, backticks, exitstatus

In my code :

```
$status = `ls -l error*`;
```

It shows output : `ls *error No such file or directory.` 
How can I suppress this message. I am interested in determining that the error files are generated or not. If yes, I need the list of files else ignore (without printing the message)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By running it like

```
$status = `ls -l error* 2> /dev/null`;
```

and suppressing the external command's output to standard error.

If you just need the file names (and not all the other info that `ls`'s `-l` switch gives you), this can be accomplished in pure Perl with a statement like

```
@files = glob("error*");
if (@files == 0) { 
    ... there were no files ...
} else { 
    ... do something with files ...
}
```

and if you do need all the other info you get from `ls -l ...`, applying the builtin [`stat`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#stat) function to each file name can give you the same information.

Comment: Thanks @mob! It worked when I used `ls -l error* 2>/dev/null` . I had tried it with `ls -l error* 2>&1` but that didnt work. A bit confused here

Comment: `2>&1` means put the standard error stream (file descriptor 2) to standard output (file descriptor 1). `2>/dev/null` means throw the standard error stream away.

Comment: Thanks! Finally understood the difference :)